# Métodos estáticos em Factory Method

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern

Estou criando uma classe utilizando *Factory Method* e me surgiu a seguinte dúvida.

É recomendável a utilização de métodos estáticos em *Factories*?

Em muitos exemplos que encontrei temos que criar uma instância da classe *Factory*, mas no meu caso não pensei em nenhuma razão para que a mesma precise ser instanciada.

```
<?php
/* Factory and car interfaces */
interface CarFactory {
    public function makeCar();
}

interface Car {
    public function getType();
}

/* Implementações da Factory e Car */
class SedanFactory implements CarFactory {
    public function makeCar() {
        return new Sedan();
    }
}

class Sedan implements Car {
    public function getType() {
        return 'Sedan';
    }
}

/* Client */
$factory = new SedanFactory();
$car = $factory->makeCar();
print $car->getType();
```

[Fonte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

Notem a diferença na implementação com métodos estáticos:

```
<?php
/* Factory and car interfaces */
interface CarFactory {
    public static function makeCar();
}

interface Car {
    public function getType();
}

/* Implementações da Factory e Carro */
class SedanFactory implements CarFactory {
    public static function makeCar() {
        return new Sedan();
    }
}

class Sedan implements Car {
    public function getType() {
        return 'Sedan';
    }
}

/* Client */
$car = SedanFactory::makeCar();
print $car->getType();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notem que existem 2 design patterns relacionados ao Factory Method:

1. Factory Method - http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method
2. Static Factory Method - http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151

Portanto, a resposta à sua pergunta é, depende do design pattern desejado.

O Factory Pattern é implementado como discutido até agora, sem métodos estáticos. Contudo, o Static Factory Method, é um pouco diferente (o exemplo é em Java mas acredito que a ideia seja a mesma):

```
public class Boolean {
  ...
  public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
     return b ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
  }
  ...
}
```

O Static Factory Method é mais simples e já retorna o tipo da prórpria classe, como no exemplo do Boolean.

Já o Factory Method, não é definido utilizando métodos estáticos. Inclusive, sua implementação na wikipedia (http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Method) não utiliza métodos estáticos.

Acredito que, há um PORÉM em tudo isso. Design Patterns são guias de boas práticas mas podem ser adaptados para nossas necessidades. Caso se instanciar objetos a toda hora que se chama o método da factory seja custoso, não vejo problemas em utilizar métodos estáticos. Contudo, isso é uma modificação do design pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Não sendo estática você ganha na "configuração" e na "troca" da sua fábrica.

Com configuração, quero dizer que você pode alterar o valor ou chamar um método qualquer da classe `SedanFactory` antes de chamar `makeCar()`, alterando como o carro será construído (como o Renan falou).

Com a troca da fábrica, quero dizer que você pode ter um método que recebe como parâmetro um objeto de uma classe qualquer que implementa `CarFactory`, sabendo que poderá chamar `makeCar()` para construir um carro sem precisar de saber se é `SedanFactory` ou `SUVFactory`.