# Para que serve o método estático of que retorna uma instância do objeto em Java

Tags: java, design-pattern, static, factory

Acredito que esse método sirva para "burlar" a **não** possibilidade de um método **construtor** estático. Mas qual a função disso?

```
public static MinhaClasse of(OutraClasse outraClasse, Departamento departamento) {
    return new MinhaClasse (outraClasse, departamento);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este é um *design pattern* conhecido como [*Static Factory Method*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/929021).

A ideia não é "burlar" nada, e sim prover algumas características que não seriam possíveis somente com o construtor.

Uma das possibilidades foi citada na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/523481/112052): controlar a quantidade de instâncias criadas. Um exemplo está na própria JVM, na classe `java.lang.Integer`, que [internamente possui um cache](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3381/112052) que guarda valores entre -128 e 127. Você pode consultar o [código fonte](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java) e ver por si mesmo, mas enfim, a implementação atual (na data em que escrevo esta resposta) é:

```java
public static Integer valueOf(int i) {
    if (i >= IntegerCache.low && i <= IntegerCache.high)
        return IntegerCache.cache[i + (-IntegerCache.low)];
    return new Integer(i);
}
```

Ou seja, o método `valueOf` está servindo como um *static factory method*. Eu até poderia usar `new Integer(1)`, só que aí eu estaria sempre criando uma nova instância, enquanto que se usar `Integer.valueOf(1)`, eu obtenho a instância que está no cache (ou seja, várias chamadas a `valueOf` usariam a mesma instância, enquanto várias chamadas ao construtor criariam várias instâncias).

Em alguns casos pode-se deixar o construtor `private`, assim a única forma de criar instâncias é usando o *static factory method*. Esta é uma decisão de *design* da API: você quer controlar a todo custo a criação de novas instâncias, ou quer deixar para o programador decidir?

---

Outra vantagem é dar mais semântica para o código. Por exemplo (usando [uma das respostas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/929273) na pergunta já citada no início), se tivesse uma classe que representa as coordenadas em um plano cartesiano, eu poderia criar uma instância usando coordenadas cartesianas ou polares:

```java
public static Coordinate createFromCartesian(double x, double y) {
    ...
}

public static Coordinate createFromPolar(double distance, double angle) {
    ...
}
```

Internamente, a classe pode guardar as coordenadas da forma que lhe convier melhor (e os métodos acima fazem as conversões necessárias em cada caso).

Já usando somente um construtor não seria possível, pois se eu declará-lo como `public Coordinate(double x, double y)`, não daria para saber qual das duas versões estou chamando (talvez teria que ter um terceiro parâmetro indicando se são coordenadas cartesianas ou polares).

---

Usando outro exemplo, você poderia ter uma classe `Temperatura`, podendo construí-la a partir de um valor em Celsius, Kelvin ou Fahrenheit:

```java
public class Temperatura {
    private double kelvin; // valor é internamente gravado em Kelvin
    private Temperatura(double kelvin) {
        this.kelvin = kelvin;
    }
    public static Temperatura fromCelsius(double graus) {
        // converte para Kelvin
        return new Temperatura(celsiusToKelvin(graus));
    }
    public static Temperatura fromKelvin(double graus) {
        return new Temperatura(graus);
    }
    public static Temperatura fromFahrenheit(double graus) {
        // converte para kelvin
        return new Temperatura(fahrenheitToKelvin(graus));
    }
}
```

Internamente o valor é guardado em Kelvin, e cada método recebe o seu respectivo valor e faz as conversões necessárias. Também poderiam ser incluídas validações (por exemplo, se o valor em Kelvin for negativo, dá erro, etc).

Outro detalhe é que assim você pode mudar detalhes internos de implementação sem afetar o uso dos *static factory methods*. Por exemplo, em vez de converter tudo para Kelvin, eu poderia guardar o valor da forma que está, e criar um outro campo indicando qual a escala utilizada (Celsius, Fahrenheit, etc). O construtor poderia mudar sem problema, mas para quem usa os métodos estáticos, nada mudaria.

Um exemplo similar está na própria JVM: na [classe `java.time.LocalDate`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/time/LocalDate.java), o construtor é só isso:

```java
private LocalDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
    this.year = year;
    this.month = (short) month;
    this.day = (short) dayOfMonth;
}
```

Ou seja, só recebe os valores do dia, mês e ano. Mas se olharmos os diversos *static factory methods*, vamos encontrar algo assim:

```java
public static LocalDate of(int year, Month month, int dayOfMonth) {
    YEAR.checkValidValue(year);
    Objects.requireNonNull(month, "month");
    DAY_OF_MONTH.checkValidValue(dayOfMonth);
    return create(year, month.getValue(), dayOfMonth);
}

public static LocalDate ofInstant(Instant instant, ZoneId zone) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(instant, "instant");
    Objects.requireNonNull(zone, "zone");
    ZoneRules rules = zone.getRules();
    ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset(instant);
    long localSecond = instant.getEpochSecond() + offset.getTotalSeconds();
    long localEpochDay = Math.floorDiv(localSecond, SECONDS_PER_DAY);
    return ofEpochDay(localEpochDay);
}
```

Ou seja, cada método específico valida os diferentes dados que recebe, e no fim todos acabam chamando o construtor: no caso, o método `create` chamado por `of` faz validações adicionais para verificar se a data é valida (se é ano bissexto e fevereiro tem 29 dias, por exemplo, além de outros casos), o método `ofEpochDay` faz uma série de cálculos para chegar aos valores corretos de dia, mês e ano, etc (e no fim, sempre acabam chamando o construtor).

Com isso você ganha mais flexibilidade, pois te dá várias opções diferentes para criar as instâncias (além de dar mais semântica, com nomes mais significativos que não seriam possíveis apenas com um construtor).

---

Indo mais além, usando um *static factory method* você pode retornar sub-classes da classe em questão, o que não é possível com um construtor, já que ele sempre retorna uma instância da classe que está construindo.

Um exemplo é a interface `java.util.List`, que a partir do Java 9 possui o método `of`:

```java
List<String> list = List.of("a", "b");
System.out.println(list.getClass()); // class java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12
```

A lista criada é uma instância de `java.util.ImmutableCollections$List12` (esta não é uma classe pública e eu não posso usá-la diretamente, mas nada impede que o *static factory method* retorne uma instância dela). Enfim, esta classe (cujo fonte pode ser consultado [aqui](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ImmutableCollections.java)) foi usada internamente pelo *static factory method* (talvez por ser uma implementação "otimizada" para este caso específico, ou qualquer outro motivo que seja), o que não seria possível com um construtor.

O mesmo acontece com métodos como `Collections.unmodifiableList` (que retorna uma lista que não pode ser modificada, que pode ou não ser instância de uma classe especializada, e não necessariamente pública), e sendo detalhes internos de implementação, podem mudar sem afetar quem usa tais métodos. Por exemplo, o código acima foi testado no Java 12, mas pode ser que em outras versões isso mude (eles podem trocar por outra classe, etc).

---

Enfim, a ideia geral é esta. Você pode consultar mais exemplos [aqui](https://www.baeldung.com/java-constructors-vs-static-factory-methods) e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/929021) (alguns eu adaptei nesta resposta, mas nos links tem mais casos).

Ver também:

- [Métodos estáticos em Factory Method](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23796/112052)
- [Implementação dos padrões Abstract Factory, Factory Method e Adapter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187062/112052)
- [Qual a diferença entre Simple Factory, Factory Method, Abstract Factory?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/112052)

Answer (score 2):

No seu exemplo não serve para nada.

Uma função estática que retorna uma instancia da classe em que ela foi declarada é uma convenção chamada *factory*. A diferença da função estática para um construtor propriamente dito, é que a função não tem a obrigação de criar uma instancia, ela apenas precisa retornar uma instancia.

Como assim?

Em situações específicas, como por exemplo quando tentando criar um *thread*, ou estabelecer uma conexão com alguma API externa, você pode ter um limite de quantas instancias desses objetos a sua máquina consegue rodar antes de comprometer a performance.

Para esses casos você pode restringir o acesso ao construtor do objeto, e encapsula-lo em uma função estática, que irá controlar se essa nova instancia será criada, se ela irá ser reciclada de alguma camada de *cache*, ou se você terá uma exceção lançada.

Comment: A resposta em si é boa, porém cadê os exemplos? as referências? veja [como escrever uma boa resposta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)